# Bessel functions in an Hermite-Gauss basis

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, special-functions

¿Could somebody tell me how can i write a zero order bessel function in an Hermite-Gauss basis?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hermite-Gauss functions (suitably normalized) are orthonormal for an inner product defined by integration, just like $\{\sin(nx),\cos(mx)\}$ as $n,m$ run over positive integers.  The coefficients of an expansion of a $J$-Bessel function in terms of Hermite-Gauss functions are computed by integrating the Bessel functions against the various Hermite-Gauss functions, in a way analogous to how a Fourier expansion is computed.  You'll want to be looking at a table of integrals, or maybe *Mathematica*.  (I'm not guaranteeing anything about the convergence of the series; I haven't thought about it that much.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!
I was thinking in an expansion tabulated yet like those appearing in Gradstein and Ryzhik, but i didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: See also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions

for details